# Points are not adding up in my score system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a scoring system for my game application and for some reason **points are not adding up**. The goal is whenever the player guesses the correct answer, points are added. For each new player, the score is set to 0.

**question#validate_answer**:

```
def validate_answer
  @correct_answer = Answer.where(correct: true).map(&:text)
  @selected_answer = params[:answer]
  @player_score = Player.where(id: params[:id]).map(&:score)

  if @correct_answer.include? (@selected_answer)
    @player_score[0] += 1
    render :success
  else
    render :error
  end
end
```

**Quesiton.rb**

```
    class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    has_many :answers

    has_one :video_clue
     has_many :answers

    def correct_answer
    answers.find_by correct: true 
    end


   end
```

**Answer.rb**

```
   class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :question

   end
```

**Player.rb**

```
 class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_secure_password

def admin?
    self.admin == 'admin'
end

end
```

**Schema Tables for Answers and Players**

```
create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "question_id"
t.string   "text"
t.boolean  "correct"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "answers", ["question_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id",   using: :btree


create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "user_name"
t.string   "password_digest"
t.integer  "score"
t.string   "role"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
end
```

Comment: hi michael. please google about testing and then write a test, to make sure, your code is working. so after you created your test, and your code fails, you know that you need to fix the model, unitll tests are passing

Comment: Ok I will as soon I get this working

Comment: and exactly that is the wrong approach to TDD. first you need to write a test, to define which outcome you expect (adding points after correct answer). after you did your test (which are failing due missing implementation) you can change your model as long as you want, knowing if its right when its passing the tests. unless its passing the tests, your model-code is wrong. thats the way of "test driven development"

Comment: check railscasts on tests

Comment: I already know about testing and I use Rspec. So what you saying is I should stop everything and write a test?

Comment: u should stop working on the "adding points" inside your model, write a test, and then you can go back to your model and fix the logic.

Comment: and btw, i recommend something like `@player.gave_correct_answer!(answer)` where then inside the method you award the points, based on the questions difficulty. maybe some questions are worth 5 points, others just 2

Comment: For which model/controller I should  write a test for? I'm not good at that stuff.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10438931 somehow like this the test should look like

Comment: Where exactly this @player.gave_correct_answer!(answer) goes? In my Question#validate_answer method?

Comment: @player is the Player class. so if u wanna call methods on that its inside the player model (player.rb?)

Comment: I'm confused. So that method should go in my player.rb ?

Comment: well, the player is getting points. so you award points to a players model. that is obviously a method inside the player class.

Comment: otherwise the question would award points to a user which is really bad architecture

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure the code the like this:

```
def validate_answer
  @question = Question.find(params[:q_id])
  @correct_answer = Answer.find_by_question_id(params[:q_id]).text.downcase
  @selected_answer = params[:answer].downcase
  @player = Player.find(params[:id])

  if @selected_answer == @correct_answer
    @player.increment!(:score)
    render :success
  else
    render :error
  end
end
```

`increment!` automatically pings the `@player` object for the column specified. It saved the trouble of trying to convert it to an array and access the index which was sort of roundabout.

**NOTE: Edited Answer per chat conversation.**

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work! I got this error  "undefined method `increment!' for #<Player::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f61caa74620>"

Comment: Replace `Player.where(id: params[:id])` with `Player.find_by(id: params[:id])` to eliminate the Relation error.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Oversight on my part. Michael - you may need to do some debugging: 1. Do you have a `score` attribute that as part of the `Player` model? 2. change your renders: change `render :success` to `render text: params` and change your `render :error` to `render text: "error"`. These will render the result in the browser window for us to work with.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed you are using `params[:id]` to find the Question and the Player.

Comment: Given that find, comment out the entire method's contents. Do this inside: `render text: params` and post them for me please.

Comment: The render :error and :success are html pages (error.html.erb , success.html.erb)that tells the player whether they got the question right or wrong.  Please disregard the question params because it really don't have anything to do with my issue. I used it for other purpose.

Comment: I still need to see what params are being passed so we can setup the controller. The controller is not handling the given parameters correctly is the one thing we do know.

Comment: Parameters is the html data that's being sent to your Rails app so that your  controller can send the request to a MVC component. I didn't need that all of the code you posted but that's ok! In your rails console, when you click the submit, you should see something that looks like this: `Processing by MichaelsController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"company_id"=>"3", "something_else"=>"this is cool", "filter"=>"filtered"}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90385/discussion-between-michael-stokes-and-miler350).

Answer (score 0):

just see how less lines of code are need to be done for that

```
def validate_answer
  #i think this is a bad approach to compare the text of the answer
  #with the text of the given answer
  #the better one would be to assing UUID to the answer or just use the regular ID
  # something like this params[:answer][:uuid]
  # or params[:answer][:id]

  # we need to find the answer related to the question, otherwise we 
  # could throw in just random IDs and they are still saying "correct"
  given_answer = Questions.find(params[:question_id]).answers.find params[:answer][:id]
  # if we use UUID we dont need to give the question id, since then the ID can't be guessed


  if given_answer.correct?
    # current_user is a player.
    # current_user is a method from devise (u should use devise)
    current_user.award_points! given_answer
    render :success
  else
    ender :error
  end 
end



class Player

  def award_points! answer
    # adding the points to the user
    # and save it

    current_user.award_points += answer.points
    current_user.save

    #better approach would be to save the question which was answered for the user
    # like has_many :answered_questions
    # so then u could also track which questions already been answered by the user and not awarding him twice
  end

end
```